# Mailto: Function opens Paypal app instead of native email app (on mobile)

Tags: email, paypal, hyperlink, mailto

i try to figure out why my mailto function doesn't work like expected. I get redirected to paypal everytime i click on it. I use an Android phone (S7).

The button link looks like this:

mailto:?subject=I%20wanted%20you%20to%20see%20this%20site&body=Check%20out%20this%20article%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Ftestsite.net%2F

Of course i could delete or disable Paypal on my phone...The problem is: i want to share the link online and if people get redirected to paypal instead this would cost me money.

There must be any solution...Do you have any ideas ?

With best Regards,
Fabi

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the paypal app icon.  Click info. Go down to settings, then where it says set as default, click "clear defaults".

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?